# Default URL directory

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, .htaccess

Working on a codeigniter project, I have now uploaded it to a live server. My issue is if I visit just the url I get nothing. I need to visit the url and than add the folder where my project is.

example `myurl.com/index`

I want it to automatically load that index folder in the url, when some just types in myurl.com

my .htaccess folder looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /index
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

also this is on a apache server.

////////////////UPDATE Cannot get images to display without .extension since moving to apache server, localhost wamp works without.

So I am allowing uploads of images, the only allowed images are .png , .jpeg and ,.jpg files types.

In the contoller I am using the time function `$image = time();` to randomize the filename. It than uploads file reference to the database and saves the file to a folder in assets as posted below,

the file path

```
src="http://mywebsite.com/index/assets/images/posts/12345678"
```

I use this to display the image on the website also.

On my localhost this works great.

On my apache live server this does not work, until I put a .png or .jpg after the file name. I went to other websites and seen that they do no have this so I know its either my htaccess or server.

Comment: Have you set `$config['base_url'] = https://yourdomain.com` in your `config.php` file?

Comment: yes I have it setup as $config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/index/'; and index is the name of the project folder.

Comment: This isn't very recommended, as you cannot control what the `HTTP_HOST` element outputs. try a FQDN. Also, note that your `.htaccess` already rewrites to `/index` so by pointing your base URL to `index` as well, you may be double-doing it. Just to be sure, the URL you'd expect to have is `example.com/index/controller/method`, correct?

Comment: Yes the url I am expecting is example.com/index/controller I do not need the method called since my controller has the index() function so it calls that automatically. I tried just using the base url and the did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +MultiViews # add this line to show images without extension.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /index
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index [L,R=301] #add this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

We match an empty request URI and redirect to `/index`.

Comment: This seems to be correct as when I type the url in I see it calls the folder automatically, but the issue now is I am getting this error "redirected you too many times." I tired clearing cookies/cache still the same thing.

Comment: @PHPNoob that is related to your below rewrite rule you have. Can you explain the `$1` in the rewrite condition ?

Comment: I was told to use that to be able to grab all of the methods/controllers after the base url

Comment: @PHPNoob ok, you can remove that as it doesn't serve any purpose and doesn't have the right syntax of capturing. I will update my post.

Comment: I got it too work, thank you so much. Really quick since you know this htaccess file stuff. I am using a apache server, and on my local wamp server images loaded fine on the website without a file extension, ever since I uploaded live to apache I cannot get images to work without a extension. What can I add in the htaccess to fix this.

Comment: @PHPNoob Can you edit your post and add an example of input and output for images? I will then update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I guess I really need to learn how to use htaccess a lot better. Thank you, you corrected my problems. Appreciate it.